# Access const defined in beforeEach within test in Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

For the given code, how can I access the const `myConst` within test `myTest`:

```
describe('HeaderCustomerDetailsComponent child components',() => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    const myConst = "Something";
  });

  it('myTest', () => {
    expect(myConst).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're defining `myConst` in the `beforeEach(...)` method its constrained to that scope. The best way to do it is to probably move `myConst` out to the class level, and define it using `let`.

Try this:

```
describe('HeaderCustomerDetailsComponent child components',() => {
  let myConst;

  beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    this.myConst = "Something";
  });

  it('myTest', () => {
    expect(this.myConst).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Since you are still setting `myConst` in the `beforeEach(...)` method you avoid pollution between tests, but you should still be careful.

Comment: Thanks!

Although I had to do:

```const myConst: myConstType = {...someting};

beforeEach(() => {
  ...
  // myConst.newProperty = 'maybe';
});

it('myTest', () => {
  expect(myConst).toBeAwesome();
});
```